# howto integrate routes and security access control

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to hide some links in template, if route or path is not allowed for logged user. Something like this:

```
{% if allowedroute 'fos_user_security_logout' %}    
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}" class="action-logout">
    {{ 'layout.logout'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
    </a>
{% endif %}
```

How to determine is it allowed in security access_control for logged user?
May be there is some functionality like this:

```
$securityContext->isRouteGranted('routeName');
or
$securityContext->isUriGranted('uri/path');
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to check access to a route from twig. However, since you have to set up security.yml access_control routes with user roles, you CAN check role-based authentication in your template:

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') %}
// logout link here
{% endif %}
```

It's not as dynamic, but unless your routes change a lot, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, but I try to determine link visibility by route or uri, using security access map. It's method can be used for many cases like KnpMenu not allowed items hiding.

Comment: I wrote MillwrightMenuBundle which extends base functionality of KnpMenuBundle and adds configuration, route, translation and security context support.

Configuration example and options descriptions in Resources/doc/index.md

https://github.com/zerkalica/MillwrightMenuBundle

Comment: do this bundle allows me to make dynamic menu like company/{id}/show company/{id}/details giving to render function twig variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want item hiding for KnpMenuBundle - [you need to extend menu renderer and menu item classes to support permissions](https://github.com/knplabs/KnpMenuBundle/issues/51). You can also try to look at [SecurityExtraBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle) for putting permissions onto controller actions and play with it to bind security permissions to routes - as far as I know, Sf2 does not have it at the moment. You could try inside your controller the following annotated example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/create", name="create_group")
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_CREATE_GROUP")
 * @Template()
 */
public function createGroupAction(Request $request) {
```